# customized rails routing url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am little bit confused in using rails route. I need some suggestion about customizing my url.

This is my current url

`http://localhost:3000/posts/product/41?product_id=2`

and

`http://localhost:3000/posts/product/41?model_id=24&product_id=2`

This is my link

```
<%= link_to product_model.name, controller: :posts,action: :product,product_id: params[:product_id],model_id: product_model.id
```

Logically product should come first in url. But why model prefers first here.

And i need my url something like this

`http://localhost:3000/posts/product/41/mobile`

and

`http://localhost:3000/posts/product/41/mobile/nokia`

Since i am not familiar with rails route i didn't write any special coding in my route

Here is the simple route exist

```
resources :posts
```

Comment: You can use friendly-Id gem.

Comment: @AmitSharma Yes i am using friendly-id only but i can work it as above

Comment: @Seting, what does the "41" stand for in your current URL?

Comment: @b.rad I have four relation `category, sub-category, product and model` 41 is sub category id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok your question here actually contains two different problems, so i will give suggestions to both.

**1. Nested resources**

Your first problem is to use "nested routes". Rails guide has a long and good article about routes and how to write and use them, including nested routes. You can check it out here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources.

However in your situation would the solution look something like this:

```
resources :category do
  resources :sub_category do
    resources :products do
      resources :models
    end
  end
end
```

You can now greate links like this

```
<%= link_to product_model.name, category_sub_category_product_model_path(@category, @sub_category, @product, product_model) %>
```

You can see that i have removed posts, see **3. Refactor design** to see why. If you really want this as a action on posts, should you however do something like this (but would recommend this!):

```
get "posts/product/:category_id/:subcategory_id/:product_id/:model_id", to "posts#product",  as: :posts_product
```

This would be used like this in your views:

```
<%= link_to product_model.name, posts_product_path(@category, @sub_category, @product, product_model) %>
```

**2. Pretty URL's**

Your second problem is to use model names instead of id's in your urls. The simpels solution for this is having a unique attribute on your model that you can use instead of id, and then just add a `to_param` method. Fx for product could we do something like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

Ryan Bates have made a good screencast about this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised. If you want something more flexible should you use the gem [Friendly Id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). And again does Ryan comes to the rescue with another great RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid.

**3. Change design**

Ok well so this is just my opinion, feel free to ignore it. But their is some bad practices and signs in your examples, so let me just quickly go through what i think you should improve on.

*Restful actions*

You should, when possible always avoid creating controller actions that is not restful (simply put is the base actions index, show, new, create, edit, update and destroy the only restful actions). In your example does this mean that the product action of the posts controller should be changed to something restful. Why not move it to the product model controller and call it "show"?

*Deeply nested resources*

You should avoid nesting your routes to deeply. Is it really important to show both the category, the sub category, the product AND the model in your url? Maybe that's how your models are associated internally in your application but why should the user know this? If you don't have a list of subcategories at "/posts/product" and a list of products at "posts/product/41" is there no reason to have so long a route. A rule of thumb is "nest no deeper then two levels", ie. ":category/:sub_category". Further more does short routes mean better SEO.

As i said, feel free to ignore these suggestions, your application would work without these changes. However changing these things would greatly help you structure you code, and keep your codebase clean and maintainable. These rules and principles is not something i have just conjured out of nothing, but very accepted principles in the Rails community. You can google each of these principles or patterns and see a lot of articles and posts on why it's a good idea to follow them, especially when you work with Rails.

**Resources**

- [**Rails Routing from the Outside In** — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
- [**norman/friendly_id** - Github](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)
- [**#314 Pretty URLs with FriendlyId** - RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid)
- [**#63 Model Name in URL (revised)** - RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [`friendly-id gem`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

There's a great [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) about it

[image: RailsCasts FriendlyID]

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your **model** in`model.rb`

```
  def to_param
    name
  end
```

and then add 
`@model = Model.find_by_name(params[:id])` to your **show** method, then you can get the url as you mentioned above.

PS: You Should have **name** field for **Model** table in your **schema**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for nested routes. Please refer this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

and use `to_param` method in the model if you want to display model_name instead of id as explained by @Ajay Kumar

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

where name is the model attribute for that specific model.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a namespace?

```
namespace :posts do
  resources :products
end
```

This should do I think..

Namespace does not include restful ids into the scope..